# $(M\models \Sigma_1\cup\Sigma_2)\leftrightarrow((\Sigma_1\rightarrow\alpha\wedge\Sigma_2\rightarrow\beta)\rightarrow M\models\alpha\wedge\beta)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I need to prove that for 2 propositions sets (that may or may not be infinite); $\Sigma_1$ and $\Sigma_2$, the 2 following proposition are equivalents

1. There is a model $M$ so that $M\models\Sigma_1\cup\Sigma_2$
2. for each $\alpha$, $\Sigma_1\Longrightarrow\alpha$, and for each $\beta$, $\Sigma_2\Longrightarrow\beta$, there is a model $M$ so $M\models\alpha\wedge\beta$

assuming (1), there is a model $M$ so for every $\varphi\in\Sigma_1\cup\Sigma_2$, $M\models\varphi$ so if $\Sigma_1\Longrightarrow\alpha$ then $M\models\alpha$ and if $\Sigma_2\Longrightarrow\beta$ then $M\models\beta$ and for this model $M$, $M\models\alpha\wedge\beta$

but I have a problem with assuming (2), I know that if $M\models\alpha\wedge\beta$ then $M\models\alpha$ and $M\models\beta$ and because $\Sigma_1\Longrightarrow\alpha$ there is a subset $K_1\subseteq\Sigma_1$ so that $K_1\Longrightarrow\alpha$ and $\Sigma_2\Longrightarrow\beta$ there is a subset $K_2\subseteq\Sigma_2$ so that $K_2\Longrightarrow\beta$ but I don't know how this helps me prove that every subset of $\Sigma_1\cup\Sigma_2$ has a model and therefore the set $\Sigma_1\cup\Sigma_2$ has a model

---

EDIT:

So I might have come up with a solution. let $\Sigma_1=\{\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n,...\}$ and $\Sigma_2=\{\psi_1,...,\psi_m,...\}$ and $\alpha_n=(\varphi_1\wedge...\wedge\varphi_n)$ and $\beta_m=(\psi_1\wedge...\wedge\psi_m)$, $\Sigma_1\Longrightarrow\alpha_n$ and $\Sigma_2\Longrightarrow\beta_m$ assuming (2), if $M_{nm}\models\alpha_n\wedge\beta_m$ then $M_{nm}\models\alpha_n$ and $M_{nm}\models\beta_m$ hence $M_{nm}\models\{\varphi_1,...,\varphi_n,\psi_1,...,\psi_m\}$ so every subset of $\Sigma_1\cup\Sigma_2$ has a model and from the compact theorem there is a model M, so that $M\models\Sigma_1\cup\Sigma_2$

Comment: do you know the compactness theorem?